# How to check which directx runtime version is installed on my windows machine?

Tags: directx

I need to do coding for 3D graphics, I would like to check which version of directx runtime is installed on my Windows machine. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open run dialog (windows + r), type 'dxdiag' and hit enter, click through WHQL yes/no question.The version is on the start page at the bottom. Alternatively System Information for Windows can probably do the same job, maybe even give more detail but I've not got my copy on me right this second.